# bootstrap 4 new line space in grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 grid.

my grid has 3 columns and each column has key value. It's a nested grid.

when key or value has more words then it comes to new line, my issue is how I can decrease space between those lines.

I would like to have no space or less space where I have shown the red lines

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 "><strong>Customer Name</strong></div>
                    <div class="col-6 ">smith</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 "><strong>Company</strong></div>
                    <div class="col-6 ">facebook</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 "><strong>header</strong></div>
                    <div class="col-6 ">value</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 "><strong>Customer Name</strong></div>
                    <div class="col-6 ">smith abcdefg xyz</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 "><strong>Company</strong></div>
                    <div class="col-6 ">This can be very long company 
                                                            name</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 "><strong>header</strong></div>
                    <div class="col-6 ">value 11111</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 "><strong>Customer Name</strong></div>
                    <div class="col-6 ">dave</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 "><strong>Company</strong></div>
                    <div class="col-6 ">Google</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 "><strong>header</strong></div>
                    <div class="col-6 ">value 11111</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

plunker for this issue

https://plnkr.co/edit/TecPEUgj7YsgnrGVZytO?p=preview

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I have my whole html now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default Bootstrap 4 line-height is `1.5`. Add some CSS to override it. For example, this would override it everywhere..

```
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
```